# How to test / measure embedded Linux startup code?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, power-management

i couldn't find any matching entries in this forum.

I've got an ARM9 Atmel SAM9G25, and it's running with an embedded Linux. Now since it's about an embedded device I want to check where i can save time and power by the startup of the device.

I know some parameters which can improve the energy savings but I only knew a few tricks to measure it. Since I not only want to test the Linux but bootstrap and u-boot in front of it too, i need a measuring method for all these 3 instances.

Can you tell which programs/algorithms can help me measure this e.g by serial port, Ethernet or by creating log files? Any links or advices?

Thanks! Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully used bootchart in the past:

http://elinux.org/Bootchart

Here is a list of other things that may also help:

http://elinux.org/Boot_Time

Comment: ah yes, those tipps seem very helpfull, thank you that helps me out. I just tried grabserial. It has an own way of working but it does it's job. But now how accurate are these results? Are they good enough for evaluating or are they affected by hard/software of the target/host?

Comment: Of course as will all performance measurements there are strange things that can effect the results. However for what you want, bootchart (and others) should easily help you identify problem areas and address them.